# rvest | Webscraping data into a long format

Tags: r, google-maps, data.table, dplyr, transformation

While web-scraping i came across the following problem for which i think there might be a better solution:

Having this data:

```
dat <- data.frame(query = c("Washington, USA", "Frankfurt, Germany"))

               query
1    Washington, USA
2 Frankfurt, Germany
```

I would like to query e.g. the [Google Maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses) and return the formatted address(es). There might be multiple formatted. The result should be the following:

```
               query         formatted_address
1    Washington, USA       Washington, DC, USA
2    Washington, USA       Washington, UT, USA
3    Washington, USA Washington, VA 22747, USA
4    Washington, USA Washington, IA 52353, USA
5    Washington, USA Washington, GA 30673, USA
6    Washington, USA Washington, PA 15301, USA
7 Frankfurt, Germany        Frankfurt, Germany
```

What i do by now is this:

```
require(RCurl)
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)

build_url <- function(x, base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="){
  paste0(base_url, RCurl::curlEscape(x))
}

l <- lapply(dat$query, function(q){
  formatted_address <- q %>% build_url %>% read_xml %>% xml_nodes("formatted_address") %>% xml_text
  data.frame(query = q, formatted_address)
})

do.call(rbind, l) # This can be done via data.table::rbindlist as well
```

Is there a better solution? Maybe more `data.table` or `dplyr` style?

Comment: please include `library`/`require` calls to make your code reproducible

Comment: Sure. Just added the `require` statements

Comment: apart from a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` on the `data.frame` creation you've optimized this perfectly IMO. I'd suggest adding a `sleep` in the `lappl` and ensuring you limit the # of calls to 2500 or fewer IIRC ([usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) info).

Answer (score 0):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API with a valid API key (so if your data is greater than 2,500 items you can pay for an API key).

To get the address details use `google_geocode()`

```
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

dat <- data.frame(query = c("Washington, USA", "Frankfurt, Germany"))

## To get all the data:
res <- apply(dat, 1, function(x){
  google_geocode(address = x["query"],
                 key = key)  ## use simplify = F to return JSON
})

## to access the 'formatted address' part, see
res[[1]]$results$formatted_address
# [1] "Washington, DC, USA"       "Washington, UT, USA"       "Washington, VA 22747, USA" "Washington, IA 52353, USA"
# [5] "Washington, GA 30673, USA" "Washington, PA 15301, USA"

## so to get everything as a list
lapply(res, function(x){
  x$results$formatted_address
})

# [[1]]
# [1] "Washington, DC, USA"       "Washington, UT, USA"       "Washington, VA 22747, USA" "Washington, IA 52353, USA"
# [5] "Washington, GA 30673, USA" "Washington, PA 15301, USA"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Frankfurt, Germany"

## and to put back onto your original data.frame:
lst <- lapply(1:length(res), function(x){
  data.frame(query = dat[x, "query"],
             formatted_address = res[[x]]$results$formatted_address)
})

data.table::rbindlist(lst)
#                 query         formatted_address
# 1:    Washington, USA       Washington, DC, USA
# 2:    Washington, USA       Washington, UT, USA
# 3:    Washington, USA Washington, VA 22747, USA
# 4:    Washington, USA Washington, IA 52353, USA
# 5:    Washington, USA Washington, GA 30673, USA
# 6:    Washington, USA Washington, PA 15301, USA
# 7: Frankfurt, Germany        Frankfurt, Germany
```